# How to install riscv-tools older version using Homebrew

Tags: linux, macos, version, homebrew, riscv

I need to use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` with Clion (on Mac) that is currently supporting only up to version 9.2, I have installed `riscv-tools` using  `brew install riscv-tools` as instructed [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html) and got the latest version which is 10.1.
After that, I tried `brew install riscv-tools@9.2.0` but got: `No available formula or cask with the name "riscv-tools@9.2.0"`

Is there any way to install a specific older version?

And how bad it is to use an usupported version of gdb with Clion? so far it seems to be working anyway.

A solution in Linux will also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get gdb 9.2, you can easily get it from `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/` where gdb 9.2 already support risc-v.

Comment: I have downloaded it but the "make" fails. How do I install it?

Comment: I am using debian buster with gnome3, and i have no problems with installing. Can you provide additional info about errors?

Comment: I installed it successfully but it does still not support the riscv, only when using riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb I am able to start the gdb.